# Date types not supported

Tags: jhipster

I'm using jhipster-uml and I'm getting errors with date types used

First, I had 
C:\Users\jb\hips\h4>jhipster-uml socle2.uml
Parser detected: VISUAL PARADIGM.

```
The type 'Org.joda.time.DateTime' isn't supported by JHipster, exiting now.
Error
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\jb\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_module
s\jhipster-uml\lib\exceptions\invalid_type_exception.js:7:34)
    at Module._compile (module.js:398:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:405:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\jb\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_module
s\jhipster-uml\lib\editors\modelio_parser.js:6:28)
    at Module._compile (module.js:398:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:405:10)
```

Changed to java.time.ZonedDateTime, same result

```
The type 'Java.time.ZonedDateTime' isn't supported by JHipster, exiting now.
```

Notice the upper char at start of package (no upper char in generated uml)

Context:
W764, uml file used is xmi export (UML2 w/ primitive UML types exported) of diagram creating through reversing .java sources, by visual paradigm 12.2 CE upped to standard edition)

Comment: I dropped some usage of generics and the complained type changed (now Void)

Comment: Not sure if this could be the issue, but both error messages have a package name that starts with an uppercase character. This should be lowercase.

Comment: Hello @MattRaible, I checked the generated .uml file. No trace of an uppercased Java package. Slashing into my model to simplify it, by dropping inheritance and generics as a start, the error changed to a complain about a Void type.

Now changed my policy, I'm "upgrading" the existing project by mimic-ing an empty JHipster project.
I exchanged with Julien, starting from existing complex entities is not the way JHipster can be used.

Comment: (continued)
I tried .java to xmi then gen : KO

JDL is not useful either (for me).

A last option I haven't tried is to generate the JDL by reflexion as inherited fields should be put in the last class of the inheritance branch
And composition is to be a 1to1 relation, not a field (to be checked)

Answer (score 0):

In case you get this message or similar when generating with JHipster-UML:

**Only use JHipster supported types**, do not use inheritance nor generics